# Landscape photos cropping incorrectly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, system.drawing, jcrop

Here is my code

```
using (var photo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(src)))
using (var result = new Bitmap(width, height, photo.PixelFormat))
{
    result.SetResolution(
    photo.HorizontalResolution,
    photo.VerticalResolution);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(photo,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                new Rectangle(x, y, width, height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        photo.Dispose();
        result.Save(Server.MapPath(src));
    }
}
```

if I choose image vertical, it works cool. But horizontal images cropping wrong areas. Every time. I'm using jcrop. I don't think jcrop cause this. But anybody think that. I can write my jcrop codes.

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I got it. This is, how is showing uploaded (not croped) image;

```
<img src="blabla.jpg" width="400px" />
```

So, Jcrop is finding points on this 400px. But Orginal image is 800px.

Comment: The proper way to solve your own question is to post the answer below.  It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is, how is showing uploaded (not croped) image;

```
<img src="blabla.jpg" width="400px" />
```

So, Jcrop is finding points on this 400px. But Orginal image is 800px.